# Adding model object in external javascript using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a small doubt.I send an attribute called "myObject" from controller using ModelMap.Now I want to use it in an external javascript.Can u tell me how to acheive it.I tried by using

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
if($("#myCheckBox").attr('checked')){
for(var i=0;i<[[${myobject}]] ; i++){
}
}
});
```

but it shows like an error in my external javascript.Can u help me solve this issue.and pls tell  me how to get objects in an external javascript using thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are case-sensitive, so `myobject` would not work for `myObject`.

Also make sure you are enabling JavaScript inlining using `th:inline`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    $('#mybutton').click(function(){
        var myObject = [[${myObject}]];
        if($("#myCheckBox").attr('checked')){
            for(var i=0;i<myObject; i++){
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Actually while writting a inline javascript file it works.But it shows error in javascript if written a external javascript file.